# I can't remember my passcode, and I can't disable Find My iPhone

Tags: iphone, restore, unlock, find-my-iphone, security

I can't remember my Passcode for my iPhone 4s and I went on to iCloud and the whole find my iPhone and because my phone is disabled and I tried to restart/restart it the wifi wont turn on and I have my data turned off all I want to do is open my phone or will I have to go to some phone shop? Please help.

Comment: start at https://iforgot.apple.com If it's locked you need to prove it's yours.

Comment: I smell a rat in here!

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't making sense.

If your device is without a network connection, you can remove find my phone from the device by signing into iCloud.com and then take the device to restore it on any computer running iTunes.

If your device has network connection, you can remote wipe it and start over to set it up.

What happens when you plug it into iTunes to restore it?

Comment: Doesn't removing Find My iPhone need a network connection? (As of 2017.)

Comment: @seaturtle I forgot to explicitly state the iCloud removal. Thanks for catching what was unsaid before I edited the answer. That would confuse most everyone as originally written.

Answer (score 2):

1. If your device is disabled because you don't know your passcode or you entered a wrong password too many times then follow this guide [here](http://www.unlockboot.com/2013/05/iphone-is-disabled-error-fix-without.html)
2. If you have a iCloud activation lock then you need to visit iforgot.apple.com to reset your iCloud password using the recovery options there.
3. If you have Both problems then first restore the device using iTunes, then reset your iCloud password from iforgot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible fix for the trouble you are having:

Before continuing, if you know your iCloud password, follow the instructions here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1212#recoverymode. Remember to still backup anyways (just in case). If you have forgotten your password, continue.

1) Connect your phone to iTunes on a Mac or PC. Next, back it up to either iCloud, the computer's hard drive, or (highly recommended) both.

2) Download the iOS 8.1 IPSW file here: http://ios8release.com/download/ios-8-stable/get-ios-8.1/ (download links on the page)

WARNING: Proceeding steps may, at worst, cause your iPhone to be wiped and/or unusable (at least, until you restore it). You could also lose some data, such as phone history or SMS history. Make sure to backup (as said above) and continue at your own risk!

3) After you have updated and downloaded the IPSW file, shut your iPhone down.

4) Make sure the iPhone is connected to ITunes and powered off.

5) Now press and hold down both the power button and the home button for about 10 seconds until the screen tells you to connect to iTunes. You are now in recovery mode.

6) iTunes should now be telling you the same thing. Now, holding the "Option" key on your Mac (or the shift key on windows), click "Restore". Now, using the finder window that comes up, find and select the IPSW file you downloaded earlier. Click "Open" and continue with the restoration.

7) Now, when the iPhone is restored, on the "Set Up iPhone" screen chose your backup restoration option and continue with the setup.

8) You should now have a passcode-free iPhone!

I really hope this helps. Please respond if anyone sees an error or if it doesn't work.